# Computing the probability of a Type II error

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I have the following information:

I know the θ of the population before hand as 0.55. Now I took 200 samples from a Bernoulli distribution `Bern(0.55)`.I have to use this random sample to carry out the large sample Z-test of

```
H0 : θ = 0.5
Ha : θ > 0.5
```

If the significance level (`α = 0.03`) for this test is 3%, how do I compute the approximate probability of a Type II error.

My solution:

As I know that, `α = 0.03` the probability of a Type I error = 0.03.

Type II error would occur when we fail to reject H0 when Ha is true. We fail to reject H0 if `Z < z 1-α` which is `pnorm(1-α) = 0.833`.

I have the following confusion with my above solution:

- But, shouldn't the Type II error occur only when Ha is true. And the above calculation would result in a large Type II error. So, should I add a conditional probability that when θ > 0.5.
- As I was already told that θ = 0.55, does this make my Ha true. And
  the Type II error is indeed 0.833 ?

Comment: I can't create tags atm, i should have added Type I & II errors in the tags. This is a question from a sample midterm paper from last year that we were given

Comment: The culture of MSE is such that the creation of new tags is *not* encouraged. If you think that a new tag should be created, there is a dedicated thread for that on meta.